# Error de interpretación pm2

Tags: nodejs, pm2

Tengo este error que me sale al tratar de correr mi programa con `pm2` me dice esto:

```sh
C:\Users\YINETH\Desktop\nodejs_compras_backend>npm start

> nodejs_compras_backend@0.0.1 start C:\Users\YINETH\Desktop\nodejs_compras_backend
> pm2 start pm2.json --only nodejs_compras_backend --env dev

[PM2][WARN] Applications nodejs_compras_backend not running, starting...
[PM2][ERROR] Error: Interpreter C:\Users\YINETH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\.bin\ts-node is NOT AVAILABLE in PATH. (type 'which C:\Users\YINETH\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\pm2\node_modules\.bin\ts-node' to double check.)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nodejs_compras_backend@0.0.1 start: `pm2 start pm2.json --only nodejs_compras_backend --env dev`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the nodejs_compras_backend@0.0.1 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\YINETH\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-09T15_46_52_510Z-debug.log
```

Como que no me carga correctamente el `script`, pero tengo bien configurado en el `pm2.json` con la ruta del script y demás.

```json
"apps": [{
  "name": "nodejs_compras_backend",
  "script": "C:/Users/YINETH/Desktop/nodejs_compras_backend/src/index.ts",
  "disable_logs": false,
  "instances": "1",
  "watch_options": {
    "followSymlinks": false
  },
  // ...
}]
```

Espero me puedan ayudar o si tienen alguna idea de como corregirlo me ayudarían mucho, muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor, el mensaje de error y el código de tu `json` deben ir en formato texto, no todos podemos ver las imágenes que publicas.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya lo corregiré amigo

Comment: lo acabo de correr @MauricioContreras

Comment: El error indica que no consigue el intérprete para TypeScript de Node (`ts-node`). ¿Seguro lo tienes todo bien configurado?

Comment: si amigo lo tengo bien configurado, lo que pasa es que estoy intentando instalarlo en otro computador y me salen esos errores y tengo bien configurado todo solo cambie la ruta del script por la nueva del computador y listo, pero no me funciona

Comment: ¿Y en el otro equipo instalaste `typescript` usando `npm install typescript`?

Comment: no amigo la verdad lo instale asi npm install -g typescript

Comment: Si migraste de pc, lo primero es un `npm install` para descargar todas las dependencias.